# Prevent attachment from being deleted from Medialibrary

Tags: wordpress, hook, attachment

In  Wordpress admin media library page (upload.php) I'd like to do some checking on delete_attachment action.

I want my custom function to fire before attachment's being deleted.

In this function I want to check for it's relations with another objects in database. And delete it only if there are no relations at all.

I use this code (in functions.php) to see if my function is fired on delete_attachment:

```
<code>
      add_action( 'delete_attachment', 'check_relations' );
      function check_relations( $post_id ){
      ?>    
          <script>
             function myFunction() {
                 alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
              }
      </script>
      <?php
      }

</code>
```

but it seems that my function's not firing at all. And image attachment is being completely deleted. What's wrong in this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you are in luck;

> Up to and including WordPress 2.7 it is fired after the attachment is deleted from the database and the file system, limiting its usefulness. As of changeset #10400 (WordPress 2.8), the action will fire before anything is deleted.

So, you can change the delete behaviour. But, you shouldn't do it with javascript. That has no effect on the PHP code executed.

```
add_action( 'delete_attachment', 'check_relations' );
function check_relations( $post_id ){
    wp_die("Sorry, you can't delete this.");
}
```

Maybe a simple `return false;` would work too.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the delete link totally using the [`wp_prepare_attachment_for_js`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_prepare_attachment_for_js/) hook. Just create a function `is_not_allowed_to_delete()` that does the check you need and returns `true` if the attachment shouldn't be deleted.

```php
function remove_media_delete_link_in_grid_view( $response, $attachment ) {
    if ( is_not_allowed_to_delete( $attachment->ID ) )
        $response['nonces']['delete'] = false;

    return $response;
}
add_filter( 'wp_prepare_attachment_for_js', 'remove_media_delete_link_in_grid_view' );
```

This works also with the "Bulk Delete" action. If the attachment has this `nonce` value `false`, it will not be deleted with the other bulk selected attachments .

But this works only with the **Grid** View that uses the `wp_prepare_attachment_for_js` hook. The **List** view doesn't use any Javascript. So, to prevent deleting media files in the List view, you have to:

- Remove the individual delete link of each media item in the list using the [`media_row_actions`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/media_row_actions/) hook.
- And remove the delete option from the bulk actions menu using the [`bulk_actions-{$screen}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/bulk_actions-this-screen-id/) hook.

```php
function remove_media_delete_link_in_list_view( $actions ) {
    if ( is_not_allowed_to_delete( $attachment->ID ) )
        unset( $actions['delete'] );

    return $actions;
}
add_filter( 'media_row_actions', 'remove_media_delete_link_in_list_view' );
```

```php
function remove_media_bulk_delete_in_list_view( $actions ) {
    unset( $actions['delete'] );

    return $actions;
}
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-upload', 'remove_media_bulk_delete_in_list_view' );
```